# Why is git merge squash Xtheirs not prefering but merging?

Tags: git, merge, squash

Looking for some clarification why my problem is appearing.

In general I have 3 files which are supposed to be overwritten every time a new commit is made to master and development branch version is supposed to be preferred.
Problem is when I make a merge --squash --Xtheirs which is supposed to prefer always development branch version but for one of the files it is sometimes  doing a simple merge and this messes up the code in file.

One reason I could possibly think is that there were 2 development branches developed the same day on based on same master and they were both merged to master the same day but git is doing a simple merge?

Situations is like this:
dev1 and dev2 branch based on same version of master and both have some new development as new commit. No conflicts except those 3 files. 
dev1 commit time is 10am and dev2 commit time is 11am.
Next happens merging them to master. dev2 is merged first. 
Everything looks ok.
Next is merged dev1 and one of those 3 files which are supposed to be overwritten gets part of dev2 and dev1 code and is corrupted.

I checked that if I would have merged them to master with same order as commit times then the file is ok. But vice versa second merge file gets corrupted. Somehow weirdly merged.

Can I somehow avoid this?

Comment: I'm not sure to get your problem but you need to make dev branch clean before merge with master.

Comment: Commit *times* are irrelevant. Only the choice of the three input commits, and their corresponding contents, is relevant. You choose two of the three inputs: one by running `git checkout` and one by name or hash ID when you say `git merge <thing>`. The third one—the most important one in a way—is the *merge base* commit and that's determined by the *commit graph*.

Comment: The `-X theirs` flag tells Git that *in the event of a conflict* during merging, it should favor "their" change (base-vs-`<thing>`) rather than your change (base-vs-HEAD). Wherever there is no conflict, `-X theirs` has no effect. Use `git log --graph` to observe the *graph* and see where the merge base comes from.